# MemSql > add column if does not exist

Tags: alter-table, singlestore

I didn't find anything in documentation regarding this part - add column to table if not exist or check if column exists.

Although there is a [way](https://docs.memsql.com/sql-reference/v5.8/describe/) to see the description of a table, but it would be nice to check it right in SQL query.

Any ideas how to do at least on of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a column exists in SQL by querying information_schema.columns and seeing if it is present there - e.g.

```
select count(*) from information_schema.columns where table_name = 't' and column_name = 'c'
```

You can add a column with ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN.